# RxDart convert Stream based on previous value

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

Lets say I have a `Stream` that emits a `List` followed by single elements like:

```dart
Stream.fromIterable([
  [1, 2, 3],
  4,
  5,
]);
```

How to convert it to a `Stream` that updates the previous element with current value and emits:

```
[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
```

Comment: a simple `Stream.map` would be enough

Comment: something like: `void main() async {
final s = Stream.fromIterable([[1, 2, 3], 4, 5]);
s.map(Appender()).listen(print);
}

class Appender {
final arr = [];
call(value) {
value is Iterable? arr.addAll(value) : arr.add(value);
return arr;
}
}`

Comment: @pskink That works, thank you!

Comment: sure your welcome, btw if you are using `RxDart` the [ScanExtension](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ScanExtension.html) could do the same imho (i did not test it though) - the docs say: *"Applies an accumulator function over a Stream sequence and returns each intermediate result. The seed value is used as the initial accumulator value"*

Comment: indeed: `Stream.fromIterable([[2, 5], 3, 7])
.scan<List>((accumulated, value, i) {
value is Iterable? accumulated.addAll(value) : accumulated.add(value);
return accumulated;
}, [])
.listen(print);` works fine: no need for `Appender` "callable" class